# How to reuse a piece of Javascript multiple times in one page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slideshow, reusability

I'm new to building websites and have a (probably quite basic) question about using a Javascript function that's been written for a slideshow. I have a one-page website which uses multiple slideshow units – made up of the slideshow div, holder and a counter (e.g. 1/4), all of which is controlled by the following js:

```
var currentSlide = 0
var totalSlides = $('.holder div').length

var nextSlide = function() {
console.log('nextSlide')
currentSlide = currentSlide + 1

if (currentSlide >= totalSlides) {
    currentSlide = 0
}

var leftPosition = (-currentSlide * 100) + 'vw'
$('.holder').css('left', leftPosition)

var slideNumber = currentSlide + 1
$('.steps').text(slideNumber + '/' + totalSlides)
}


var prevSlide = function() {

  currentSlide = currentSlide - 1


if (currentSlide < 0) {
  currentSlide = totalSlides - 1
}


var leftPosition = (-currentSlide * 100) + 'vw'
$('.holder').css('left', leftPosition)

var slideNumber = currentSlide + 1
$('.steps').text(slideNumber + '/' + totalSlides)

}

var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
  nextSlide()
}, 100000000)

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide)
  nextSlide()
})

$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide)
  prevSlide()
})


var slideNumber = currentSlide + 1
$('.steps').text(slideNumber + '/' + totalSlides)

$('body').on('keydown', function(event) {

  var keyCode = event.keyCode

  if (keyCode == 37) {
    clearInterval(autoSlide)
    prevSlide()
  }

  if (keyCode == 39) {
    clearInterval(autoSlide)
    nextSlide()
  }

})
```

My set up in HTML is this:

```
<main class="scroll-container">
         <section id="project-1" class="toxic-yellow">
         <div class="slideshow">
           <div class="holder">
             <div class="slide-1 image next"><img src="images/01.jpg"></div>
             <div class="slide-2 image next">
               <p class="project-text">
                 Project 1, 3D, 2020<br>
                 Insert the project text here insert the project text here insert the project text here insert the project text here insert the project text here
               </p>
             </div>
             <div class="slide-3 image next"><img src="images/05.jpg"></div>
             <div class="slide-4 image next"><img src="images/02.jpg"></div>
             <div class="slide-5 image next"><img src="images/04.jpg"></div>
             <div class="slide-6 image next"><img src="images/06.jpg"></div>
           </div>
         </div>
           <p class="caption">Project 1</p>
           <p class="steps"></p>
         </section>
         <section id="project-2" class="lilac">
         <div class="slideshow">
           <div class="holder">
             <div class="slide-1 image next"><img src="images/05.jpg"></div>
             <div class="slide-2 image next">
               <p class="project-text">
                 Project 1, 3D, 2020<br>
                 Insert the project text here insert the project text here insert the project text here insert the project text here insert the project text here
               </p>
             </div>
             <div class="slide-3 image next"><img src="images/05.jpg"></div>
             <div class="slide-4 image next"><img src="images/02.jpg"></div>
             <div class="slide-5 image next"><img src="images/04.jpg"></div>
             <div class="slide-6 image next"><img src="images/06.jpg"></div>
           </div>
         </div>
           <p class="caption">Project 2</p>
           <p class="steps"></p>
         </section>
```

And so on. I have 12 slideshows in total on the same page. The problem I'm encountering is that the script applies globally across the whole page but I'd like to control each slideshow independently of each other. Is there a way to reuse this script and apply it separately to each instance of the slideshow?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can have a button in there? if so, you can use an `onclick` event

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript Functions or Classes.

[W3Schools Reference Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

[W3Schools Reference Classes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp)

Comment: Thank you korki for the useful links. I guess using the function or class format means I can save it to use again later? I've added the following to my js file:

function slideShow() {
(code sits here)
}

I guess the next step would be applying this to each of the slideshow sections separately. Could you possibly advise or link to something that would help with that? Many thanks! (:

Comment: Call the Function for every Slideshow you want to make. pay Attention to the Fact that Variables will be rewritten b other Slideshows. If my answer was usefull please accept it.

Comment: 'You can use functions' is hardly an answer... i would not agree is this was an accepted answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('keydown', function(event)
```

With this you are applying change to all of the elements.


Judging by your code, you can trigger the event listener to change the slides only to the child elements of the parent element(`section`) which has id  of "project-X". Have a look [here](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: Thank you – this makes sense and thanks for sharing the article. I've read it over however I'm still unsure as to how to implement it into my specific code.

Are you referring to the entire code or only the keydown event function?